# Parsing CSV datafile with nested string Dictionary

Tags: python, json, csv, datetime

I'm trying to use a large amount (20GB, approx 1000 files) of csv data from Telegram collected via Telethon over a couple weeks. I collected other data previously, but unfortunately, I completely messed up, used the wrong script and let my collection script run without attempting to parse the new output until it was complete. I've been banging my head on this for a couple days.

I need to fix the data so I can read it into a DataFrame.

Data structure from the CSV:

- Index: integer
- parent_msg_id: integer
- message_dict : string dictionary

Example of the header and first line of the csv file.

```
,parent_msg_id,message_dict
0,2103,"{...}"
```

message_dict is giving me the real problem. It is not valid JSON that I'm able to convert to dictionary (with json.loads or ast.literal_eval) easily due to a few issues.

- Use of ' instead of " ('message' item often has both as punctuation, so a simple str.replace() can't be used on the entire string)
- datetime wasn't converted to text format and was saved as datetime object (sometimes occurs in 'date' and 'edit_date' value)
- datetime formatting inconsistent
- 'media' values can be very long and contain linebreak codes

An example below:

```
"{'_': 'Message', 
'id': 29903, 
'peer_id': {'_': 'PeerChannel', 'channel_id': 1333360824}, 
'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 15, 2, 31, 58, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
'message': 'Let's all go here: https://twitter.com/i/status/1470455120513142792', 
'out': False, 
'mentioned': False, 
'media_unread': False, 
'silent': False, 
'post': False, 
'from_scheduled': False, 
'legacy': False, 
'edit_hide': False, 
'pinned': False, 
'from_id': {'_': 'PeerUser', 'user_id': 331122594}, 
'fwd_from': None, 
'via_bot_id': None, 
'reply_to': {'_': 'MessageReplyHeader', 'reply_to_msg_id': 29738, 'reply_to_peer_id': None, 'reply_to_top_id': None}, 
'media': {'_': 'MessageMediaWebPage', 'webpage': {'_': 'WebPage', 'id': 8720606894401618080, 'url': 'https://twitter.com/status/1470455120513142792', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/status/1470455120513142792', 'hash': 0, 'type': 'photo', 'site_name': 'Twitter', 'title': 'title', 'description': 'wordswordwords', 'photo': {'_': 'Photo', 'id': 5890060159542209872, 'access_hash': 6113394333987761493, 'file_reference': b'\x00a\xed\xd6|\x0e\x83\xbe(\xc0\xb9^u\x8a\x19\xb9\xe6\xe5\xbf\xd5v', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 13, 18, 12, 41, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'sizes': [{'_': 'PhotoStrippedSize', 'type': 'i', 'bytes': b'\x01\x17(g\x98\x80p\x94\xe8\xa4\x05r\xea?\x01T\xee\x18\xa1\n28\xcd6)\x88\x95\x0b\x1f\x978#\xda\x804%\xf2\xc8\x04\xc7\xd4qL\x08\x87<b\xadj\x11\x84\x81\n\x91\x81\xeb\xde\xa9\x15!2d\x07\xb6\x07n\xb4\xef\xa0%\xae\xa4\x8c""\'\x0b\x19\xa2\xaa\xa4\xa7p\xe4dQT\x996\x18F\xf3\x9e\xb9\xe2\x9c\xa8\xa3\xf8:\xf7\xa2\x8a\x83A\xd2\xcb+\x95\xcb\x16\xdb\xd0\x13Q\x05|\x92\x7f\x9d\x14P!6\xb6\xec\x9e\x87\xbd\x14Q@\x1f'}, {'_': 'PhotoSize', 'type': 'm', 'w': 320, 'h': 180, 'size': 13886}, {'_': 'PhotoSize', 'type': 'x', 'w': 800, 'h': 450, 'size': 48906}, {'_': 'PhotoSizeProgressive', 'type': 'y', 'w': 1200, 'h': 675, 'sizes': [10804, 24072, 30765, 43577, 73327]}], 'dc_id': 4, 'has_stickers': False, 'video_sizes': []}, 'embed_url': None, 'embed_type': None, 'embed_width': None, 'embed_height': None, 'duration': None, 'author': '@who', 'document': None, 'cached_page': None, 'attributes': []}}, 
'reply_markup': None, 
'entities': [{'_': 'MessageEntityUrl', 'offset': 0, 'length': 48}], 
'views': None, 
'forwards': None, 
'replies': None, 
'edit_date': None, 
'post_author': None, 
'grouped_id': None, 
'restriction_reason': [], 
'ttl_period': None}"
```

What I've tried:

I created a very... inventive hacker-ish attempt by throwing the kitchen sink at the problem. Using regex to separate out the message text, replace the other ' with ", regex again to identify datetime text, convert datetime object text to isoformat strings, and delete some of the troublesome metadata. The regex code is very slow, but it works. I would really appreciate some sort of feedback. At this rate, it might be faster to just start over.

```
rmsg = re.compile("'message': (.*?), 'out': ")
rdate = re.compile('"date": (.*?), "message": ')
rmedia = re.compile('"media": (.*?), "reply_markup": ')
reditdate = re.compile('"edit_date": (.*?), "post_author": ')

for filename in workingfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
    if len(df) == 0:
        continue
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for row in df.iterrows():
        #the actual dictionary that needs to be fixed
        messagedict = row[1]['message_dict']
        

        #return the message text and save it
        msg = rmsg.search(messagedict)
        if msg:
            messagetxt = msg.group(1)

        #split dictionary before and after message text
        splitmsg = messagedict.split(messagetxt,1)
        
        #replace ' with "
        part1 = splitmsg[0].replace("'", '"')
        part2 = splitmsg[1].replace("'", '"')
        #combine
        correctedmsg = part1 + messagetxt + part2
        
        #pull datetime string
        mdate = rdate.search(correctedmsg)
        if mdate:
            datetime_string = mdate.group(1)
        
        #convert datetime to isoformat
        datestrformat = 'datetime.datetime(%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)'
        datestrformat2 = 'datetime.datetime(%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)'
        try:
            datetext = str(datetime.strptime(datetime_string,datestrformat).isoformat())
            #print(datetext)
        except Exception as e: 
            #print (e)
            datetext = str(datetime.strptime(datetime_string,datestrformat2).isoformat())
        
        
        mmedia = rmedia.search(correctedmsg)
        if mmedia:
            media = mmedia.group(1)
        
        #replace media text with 'yes' to indicate it was a media message
        if media != 'None':
            part1 = correctedmsg.split(media,1)[0]
            part2 = correctedmsg.split(media,1)[1]
            correctedmsg = part1 + '"' + 'Yes' + '"' + part2
            
        newline = correctedmsg.split(datetime_string)[0] + '"' + datetext + '"' + correctedmsg.split(datetime_string)[1]

        meditdate = reditdate.search(correctedmsg)
        if meditdate:
            editdate = meditdate.group(1)
            replacedate = 'None'
        if editdate != 'None':
            part1 = newline.split(editdate,1)[0]
            part2 = newline.split(editdate,1)[1]
            newline = part1 + '"' + 'Yes' + '"' + part2


        linedict = ast.literal_eval(newline)

        new_df = new_df.append(linedict, ignore_index=True)
    
    df = pd.concat([df['parent_msg_id'],new_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how a big a problem this is for you, but I'd be considering starting over.  Otherwise, good work on the "kitchen sink", you got it working 

Comment: Yeah I've already created the correct script to scrape the data source again. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @Mahkus it's not clear to me what you are asking ... Do you want to make it faster ? Or do you want to make it work flawlessly ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's write a parser !

```
import datetime  # seems unused, but actually required to `eval` the datetimes
import json
import string
from typing import Tuple, Union, Dict, Any, List


def find_next_single_quote(text: str, start_pos: int, allow_unescaped=False) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    assert text[start_pos] == "'"
    # find the next unescaped single-quote
    current_pos = start_pos + 1
    while True:
        end_pos = text.find("'", current_pos)
        if end_pos == -1:
            raise ValueError("could not find closing quote")
        # it may be an escaped quote
        count_of_backslashes_before = len(tuple(c for c in text[:end_pos - 1:-1] if c == "\\"))
        if count_of_backslashes_before % 2 == 0:
            # there is no backslash, or only backslashes themselves escaped (pairs)
            # but it can be an unescaped quote, so we try to detect for that
            if allow_unescaped and end_pos + 1 <= len(text) and text[end_pos + 1] not in ",}]":  # end of token
                current_pos = end_pos + 1
                continue
            else:
                return text[start_pos + 1:end_pos], end_pos + 1
        else:
            # false positive
            current_pos = end_pos + 1
            continue


def get_json_key(text: str, start_pos: int) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    return find_next_single_quote(text, start_pos)


def get_json_val(text: str, start_pos: int) -> Tuple[Union[str, float, Dict[str, Any], bool, None, bytes, List[Any]], int]:
    if text[start_pos] == "'":  # it's a string
        return find_next_single_quote(text, start_pos, allow_unescaped=True)
    elif text[start_pos] in string.digits:
        current_pos = start_pos + 1
        while text[current_pos] in string.digits:
            current_pos += 1
        return int(text[start_pos:current_pos]), current_pos
    elif text[start_pos] == "{":
        return read_dict(text, start_pos)
    elif text[start_pos:].startswith("datetime"):
        end_pos = text.find(")", start_pos + 1)
        result_datetime = eval(text[start_pos:end_pos + 1])  # quick but dirty
        return result_datetime, end_pos + 1
    elif text[start_pos:].startswith("False"):
        return False, start_pos + 5
    elif text[start_pos:].startswith("True"):
        return True, start_pos + 4
    elif text[start_pos:].startswith("None"):
        return None, start_pos + 4
    elif text[start_pos] == 'b':
        return find_next_single_quote(text, start_pos + 1, allow_unescaped=True)
    elif text[start_pos] == "[":
        return read_list(text, start_pos)


def seek_next_item(text: str, start_pos: int) -> int:
    assert text[start_pos] == ","
    assert text[start_pos + 1] == " "
    return start_pos + 2


def read_list(text: str, start_pos: int=0) -> Tuple[List[Any], int]:
    assert text[start_pos] == "["
    current_pos = start_pos + 1
    result = []
    first = True
    while text[current_pos] != "]":
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            current_pos = seek_next_item(text, current_pos)
        item, current_pos = get_json_val(text, current_pos)
        result.append(item)
    return result, current_pos + 1


def seek_next_key(text: str, start_pos: int) -> int:
    assert text[start_pos] == ","
    assert text[start_pos + 1] == " "
    if text[start_pos + 2] == "\n":  # top-level dict
        assert text[start_pos + 3] == "'"
        return start_pos + 3
    else:
        assert text[start_pos + 2] == "'"
        return start_pos + 2


def read_dict(text: str, start_pos: int=0) -> Tuple[Dict[str, Any], int]:
    assert text[start_pos] == "{"
    current_pos = start_pos + 1
    result = {}
    first = True
    while text[current_pos] != "}":
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            current_pos = seek_next_key(text, current_pos)
        key, current_pos = get_json_key(text, current_pos)
        # print("key", repr(key), current_pos)
        assert text[current_pos] == ":"
        assert text[current_pos + 1] == " "
        current_pos += 2
        # val, current_pos = get_json_val(text, current_pos)
        print("val", repr(val), current_pos)
        result[key] = val
    return result, current_pos + 1


full_result, _ = read_dict("""{'_': 'Message', 
'id': 29903, 
'peer_id': {'_': 'PeerChannel', 'channel_id': 1333360824}, 
'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 15, 2, 31, 58, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
'message': 'Let's all go here: https://twitter.com/i/status/1470455120513142792', 
'out': False, 
'mentioned': False, 
'media_unread': False, 
'silent': False, 
'post': False, 
'from_scheduled': False, 
'legacy': False, 
'edit_hide': False, 
'pinned': False, 
'from_id': {'_': 'PeerUser', 'user_id': 331122594}, 
'fwd_from': None, 
'via_bot_id': None, 
'reply_to': {'_': 'MessageReplyHeader', 'reply_to_msg_id': 29738, 'reply_to_peer_id': None, 'reply_to_top_id': None}, 
'media': {'_': 'MessageMediaWebPage', 'webpage': {'_': 'WebPage', 'id': 8720606894401618080, 'url': 'https://twitter.com/status/1470455120513142792', 'display_url': 'twitter.com/status/1470455120513142792', 'hash': 0, 'type': 'photo', 'site_name': 'Twitter', 'title': 'title', 'description': 'wordswordwords', 'photo': {'_': 'Photo', 'id': 5890060159542209872, 'access_hash': 6113394333987761493, 'file_reference': b'\x00a\xed\xd6|\x0e\x83\xbe(\xc0\xb9^u\x8a\x19\xb9\xe6\xe5\xbf\xd5v', 'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 13, 18, 12, 41, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'sizes': [{'_': 'PhotoStrippedSize', 'type': 'i', 'bytes': b'\x01\x17(g\x98\x80p\x94\xe8\xa4\x05r\xea?\x01T\xee\x18\xa1\n28\xcd6)\x88\x95\x0b\x1f\x978#\xda\x804%\xf2\xc8\x04\xc7\xd4qL\x08\x87<b\xadj\x11\x84\x81\n\x91\x81\xeb\xde\xa9\x15!2d\x07\xb6\x07n\xb4\xef\xa0%\xae\xa4\x8c""\'\x0b\x19\xa2\xaa\xa4\xa7p\xe4dQT\x996\x18F\xf3\x9e\xb9\xe2\x9c\xa8\xa3\xf8:\xf7\xa2\x8a\x83A\xd2\xcb+\x95\xcb\x16\xdb\xd0\x13Q\x05|\x92\x7f\x9d\x14P!6\xb6\xec\x9e\x87\xbd\x14Q@\x1f'}, {'_': 'PhotoSize', 'type': 'm', 'w': 320, 'h': 180, 'size': 13886}, {'_': 'PhotoSize', 'type': 'x', 'w': 800, 'h': 450, 'size': 48906}, {'_': 'PhotoSizeProgressive', 'type': 'y', 'w': 1200, 'h': 675, 'sizes': [10804, 24072, 30765, 43577, 73327]}], 'dc_id': 4, 'has_stickers': False, 'video_sizes': []}, 'embed_url': None, 'embed_type': None, 'embed_width': None, 'embed_height': None, 'duration': None, 'author': '@who', 'document': None, 'cached_page': None, 'attributes': []}}, 
'reply_markup': None, 
'entities': [{'_': 'MessageEntityUrl', 'offset': 0, 'length': 48}], 
'views': None, 
'forwards': None, 
'replies': None, 
'edit_date': None, 
'post_author': None, 
'grouped_id': None, 
'restriction_reason': [], 
'ttl_period': None}""")
print(
    json.dumps({
        "message": full_result["message"],
        "date": full_result["date"],
        "media": full_result["media"],
        "edit_date": full_result["edit_date"]
    }, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
)
```

```json
{
    "date": "2021-12-15 02:31:58+00:00",
    "edit_date": null,
    "media": {
        "_": "MessageMediaWebPage",
        ...
    },
    "message": "Let's all go here: https://twitter.com/i/status/1470455120513142792"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely the kind of solution I was looking for and I'm working my way through it to better understand the algorithm. It does appear that the `# val, current_pos = get_json_val(text, current_pos)` line was mistakenly commented out. I'm finding some other dictionary entries that it has issues with: negative integer items ie. `'key': -123456`, which are easy to correct with `elif text[start_pos] in (string.digits + '-'):`.  It does appear that `\n` and `\'` are causing issues when they're in the message text. I'm trying to figure out a solution now

Comment: @Mahkus indeed, you spotted an error ! I meant to comment out the print on the line after. Yeah, the apostrophes are a pain in the back, I had to search for a way to tell if it was actual content or not, so I used the heuristic that if it followed by one of `",}]"`, then it must be syntax. If you post the parts that are still annoying you, I may take a look.